# Java generics to support only predefined datatypes

Tags: java, generics

I'd like to use define a generic class in java, that can only be instantiated using my custom data types that all share the same base class. Is it possible to do so without checking the datatype at runtime? Furthermore I'd like to prohibit instantiating a generic class without providing a datatype.

Edit: 
I writing a java wrapper for my c++ library and therefore the java class should only allow wrapper classes for my c++ datatypes as parameters. I just tried using bounded type parameters, as suggested, but then I can still instantiate an object like this:

```
MyClass c = new MyClass();
```

This is basically the code:

```
public class MyClass<T extends MyType>
{ 
    public MyClass()
    {

    }

    public doSomething(MyOtherClass<T> other)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Looking at the answeres below, I think this question could use a bit of elaboration or example.

Comment: This is not a generics question, it's on inheritance and polymorphism. Look those notions up and then look up how they work in Java.

Comment: public <pizza> void myAddition(pizza a, pizza b) {
  int temp = 0;
  temp = a + b; <Error -- *********
  System.out.println("Addition Value is" + temp);
 }
 
 public static void main(String[] args) {
   DDHGeneric temp = new  DDHGeneric();
   temp.myAddition(new Integer(5), 4);
 }
Is there a way with generics that you can use the addition operator even if you do not know the data type in advance. Because in this addition I want to be able to add integers, floats and it gives me an error on the + operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is called [Bounded Type Parameters](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bounded.html):

> There may be times when you'll want to restrict the kinds of types that are allowed to be passed to a type parameter. For example, a method that operates on numbers might only want to accept instances of Number or its subclasses. This is what bounded type parameters are for.

```
public <U extends Number> void inspect(U u){
    System.out.println("T: " + t.getClass().getName());
    System.out.println("U: " + u.getClass().getName());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Due to *type erasure* -- and the now very old requirement for backwards-compatibility -- there is no way to *require* that a class is instantiated with generic type parameters. Two solutions:

1. Heed the warnings. Let the developers who don't feel the wrath of run-time exceptions :-)
2. Only allow access through classes that extend the generic class (and provide type parameters). For instance, `class MyClassFoo extends MyClass<Foo>` and then hide the `MyClass` constructor from external code.

Neither is ideal, but it is what it is. Both C++ and .NET work differently, but then again they are C++/.NET and not Java :-)

Happy coding.

Answer (score 1):

If you're worried about others creating their own subclass of your base class and using this in your generic type, the only way you can prohibit this is to control extension to your base class.

One way is to protect the base class's constructor using default visibility and put the concrete implementations in the same class.  Make those concrete implementations final, or make their constructors private.